# Wifi issues on 16.04 and 17.1

Tags: 16.04, wireless, 17.10

I originally downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 and had problems with the wifi. After reading what felt like a hundred forums and attempting a hundred solutions I decided to ask a forum board I'm in for the programming course I've just begun. Someone said that they thought the problem was fixed with 17.10 but I still seem to have the same problem. My connection is sluggish at best. I can connect to my wifi and as soon as I connect through ethernet my internet runs beautifully. The frustrating part is that my wifi is just as fast on windows as it is on ethernet through linux. Any and all help will be appreciated and I'll take screenshots of whatever code or info may help diagnose and eliminate this issue so that I can get on with my life!!!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. Posting a question here with such ramblings but without actually identifying the hardware suggests you've been all over the place except where you should've looked at. Most solutions for Wifi are hardware specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check your wifi driver name using this command.

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Check your driver name in the ***-network** section.

It will look something like this :

```
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 00
   serial: 48:e2:44:90:4d:61
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
```

If You have a **Realtek** WiFi driver then this solution will work.

I had problems with my Realtek WiFi driver. Solved the issue by installing this driver.
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

If you also have a Realtek driver in your system then **Download** the driver from github. Then **Extract** the .zip file.

Next change the Directory to **rtlwifi_new-master** folder.

Then install the driver using the following commands

```
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot and enjoy

If you still have problems (low signal), you may need to add an option:`

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"  | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Then Reboot Again.

`

Comment: and what if it is not Realtek?

Comment: This solved my problem!